# Initialize a singleton after configuring dependency injection, but before the first http request

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions version 2.x. It has [built-in support for dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection).

So I can register my service IMyService for DI at singleton scope using:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOther, DefaultOther>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService, DefaultMyService>();  // IMyService depends on IOther.
    }
}
```

An instance of `DefaultMyService` is created the first time the function gets executed. This means the first request is slower because it does heavy initialization that happens inside `DefaultMyService` (it populates cache, etc.).

**Question: Is there a way to have `DefaultMyService` created earlier than the first request?**

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005861/asp-net-core-initialize-singleton-after-configuring-di) was asked for asp.net core, and the answers there suggests a few solutions, but none of them works in the context of a function app:

Option 1: Create an instance of my service (initialization happens here), and then register the instance (instead of registering the type)

```
var foo = new Foo();
services.AddSingleton<IFoo>(foo);
```

This doesn't work because in my case `IMyService` depends on other services, which are not instantiated at the time when I am registering `IMyService` in the `Configure` method. It fails with an error that's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900982/weird-exception-when-trying-to-use-dependency-injection-in-an-azure-function).

Option 2: Other suggestion is to use overloaded Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IFoo foo) 
{
    ...
}
```

This also doesn't work because in case of function app, the only configure method that gets executed is `Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)`, and other overloads are not called.

Comment: After deployment, schedule a diagnostic method call.  Not only will this test health but also get the function to be in a _warm_ state in preparation for the first client call

Comment: How/where are the other dependencies registered?

Comment: @Nkosi In the same method, but before IMyService. Also it depends on ILoggerFactory which is pre-registered by the function app host before Configure is called. I edited the code sample in question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

> because it does heavy initialization that happens inside DefaultMyService

This is where the core of the problem lies. As Mark Seemann explained [here](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), Injection constructors should do nothing more checking for null and storing incoming dependencies. Any time you do any I/O or invoke the class's dependencies *inside* the constructor, you'll get in trouble.

Your question seems similar to [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924027/avoiding-all-di-antipatterns-for-types-requiring-asynchronous-initialization/46027058#46027058), and my advise would be the same: extract the initialization logic out of the constructor and either do the following:

- Do the initialization before wiring the object graph and supply the DI configuration with an initialized object, or
- Resolve and invoke an object graph directly after the registration phase, and before the first request, in such way that the data can be initialized.