# .Net Core MVC multiple scheduled Quartz jobs and singleton scopes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, quartz.net

I am making a messaging system with scheduled jobs to send sms messages and emails from queues. However, I cannot get the below code to work with multiple jobs, it works with a single job. I am also having an issue with the job erroring with "Cannot consume scoped service !!!the context!!! from singleton !!!the job!!!".

The below is my attempt at implementing multiple jobs.

QuartzServicesUtilities

```
 public static class QuartzServicesUtilities
   {
       public static void StartJob<TJob>(IScheduler scheduler, string cron)
            where TJob : IJob
    {
        var jobName = typeof(TJob).FullName;

        var job = JobBuilder.Create<TJob>()
            .WithIdentity(jobName)
            .Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .ForJob(job)
            .WithCronSchedule(cron, x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires())
            .WithIdentity($"{jobName}.trigger")
            .StartNow()
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

QuartzExtensions

```
public static class QuartzExtensions
{
    public static void UseQuartz(this IServiceCollection services, params Type[] jobs)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, JobFactory>();
        services.Add(jobs.Select(jobType => new ServiceDescriptor(jobType, jobType, ServiceLifetime.Singleton)));

        services.AddSingleton(provider =>
        {
            var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
            scheduler.JobFactory = provider.GetService<IJobFactory>();
            scheduler.Start();
            return scheduler;
        });
    }
}
```

JobFactory

```
public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public JobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        var jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;
        var job = (IJob)_serviceProvider.GetService(jobDetail.JobType);

        return job;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        if (job is IDisposable disposable)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

SMSJob

```
public class SMSJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IMessagingRepository _messagingRepository;
    private readonly ISMSEngine _smsEngine;

    public SMSJob(IMessagingRepository messagingRepository, ISMSEngine smsEngine)
    {
        _smsEngine = smsEngine;
        _messagingRepository = messagingRepository;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
       !!! the job !!!

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

EmailJob

```
public class EmailJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IEmailEngine _emailEngine;
    private readonly IMessagingRepository _messagingRepository;

    public EmailJob(IMessagingRepository messagingRepository, IEmailEngine emailEngine)
    {
        _emailEngine = emailEngine;
        _messagingRepository = messagingRepository;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {

        !!! the other job !!!

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Startup

```
  public class Startup
  {
      public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
      {
          Configuration = configuration;
        }

      public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        var scheduler = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IScheduler>();

        QuartzServicesUtilities.StartJob<EmailJob>(scheduler, settings.Value.EmailCronSchedule);
        QuartzServicesUtilities.StartJob<SMSJob>(scheduler, settings.Value.SMSCronSchedule);
    }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed
            // for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

        #region Engines

        !!! engines !!!

        #endregion Engines

        #region Providers

        !!! providers !!!

        #endregion Providers

        #region Repositories

        !!! repos !!! i.e.
        services.AddTransient<IMessagingRepository, MessagingRepository>();

        #endregion Repositories

        services.AddDbContext<Context>();

        services.UseQuartz(typeof(EmailJob));
        services.UseQuartz(typeof(SMSJob));

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're likely running into a "captive dependency" issue where a dependency has a shorter lifetime (e.g. Scoped) than the dependent class (e.g. Singleton). See this answer for a solution to that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511175/5803406

Comment: Thank you, man, for your code. you really helped me to save my time! Love you! )))