# Cannot resolve 'xxx' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'yyy'

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I am working with a .Net WinForms Application that is being designed to collect records from MongoDB and insert records into a SQL Server database.

The error that I am getting below is flagged at Application.Run(...)

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve 'FixSqlChatHistory.WinForm.MongoReader' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'FixSqlChatHistory.DataContext.MongoToSqlContext'.'

The code I am working with is

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
    ServiceProvider = host.Services;

    Application.Run(ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MongoReader>());
}

public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }
static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
{
    var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(x => x.GetName().Name.Contains("FixSqlHistory"));

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    Configuration = builder.Build();

    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddScoped<IMongoReader, MongoService>();
            services.AddScoped<IChatActivityReader, ChatDataFixService>();
            services.AddScoped<IChatActivityWriter, ChatDataFixService>();
            services.AddAutoMapper(assemblies);
            
            services.AddDbContext<MongoToSqlContext>(options => options.
                UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
            services.AddScoped<MongoReader>();


        });
}
```

The MongoReader (Form) is constructed like this

```
public MongoReader(
    MongoToSqlContext databaseContext,
    IChatActivityReader chatActivityReader,
    IChatActivityWriter chatActivityWriter,
    IMongoReader mongoReader)
{
    _databaseContext = databaseContext;
    _chatActivityReader = chatActivityReader;
    _chatActivityWriter = chatActivityWriter;
    _mongoReader = mongoReader;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Its been a long time since I created a WinForms Application, and the first time in .Net6 so would appreciate some assistance in where I have gone wrong.

I have looked here which appears to be a similar issue but I am setup with AddScoped as this post suggests

[Cannot resolve 'ServiceBusConsumer' from root provider because it requires scoped service DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102376/cannot-resolve-servicebusconsumer-from-root-provider-because-it-requires-scope)

Comment: Have you tried adding the form as transient to the ServiceCollection?

Comment: @Caveman74, yes I tried that and get the exact same error

Comment: I don't know WinForms in with SQL injection, so I cannot provide a clear solution at this point.  The problem seems to be that either you are not defining the IoC scope or that in WinForms nothing is scoped so all must be registered as AddSingleton()?  Learn about the scopes in WinForms and you'll be able to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either [create scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386597/2501279) manually:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    // ...
    ServiceProvider = host.Services;

    using var scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope();

    Application.Run(scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MongoReader>());
}
```

Or register everything with corresponding lifetime ([`AddDbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions-adddbcontext-1(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicelifetime-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicelifetime)) allows to specify context lifetime which differs from the default `Scoped` one).

Note that depending on the app you potentially will not want to have the same context used for all it's lifetime.