# Do I need to Dispose dbconext EF 3.1?

Tags: entity-framework, dispose

Do I need to dispose the dbconext in the GetSubmissionDetailsAsync method?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddScoped(provider=>provider.GetService<IMLDbContextFactory().CreateElmsDbContext());
}
```

---

```
  public ElmsContext CreateElmsDbContext()
  {
            var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("elmsdatabase");
                var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElmsContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            return new ElmsContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
  }
```

---

```
public class DataAccessObject : IDataAccessObject
    {
        private readonly ILoggerAdapter<DataAccessObject> _logger;
        private readonly ElmsContext _elmsContext;
        private readonly ElmsPolicyContext _elmsPolicyContext;

        public DataAccessObject(ElmsContext elmsContext, ElmsPolicyContext elmsPolicyContext, ILoggerAdapter<DataAccessObject> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _elmsContext = elmsContext;
            _elmsPolicyContext = elmsPolicyContext;
        }
     public async Task<CertifiedBusinessSubmissionDto> GetSubmissionDetailsAsync(int? submissionId)
     {     
                var subId = new SqlParameter("submission_id", submissionId);
                var submission = await _elmsContext.CertifiedBusinessSubmissionDTO
                    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.get_info @submission_id", subId)
                    .ToListAsync();
              
                return submission != null && submission.Count > 0 ? submission.FirstOrDefault() : null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the code formatting. That said, your code doesn't show where `_elmsContext` comes from so we can't guess its expected life span.

Comment: Dependency Injection container. in startup class. there is services.AddScoped.

Comment: @retide That doesn't tell us where `_elmsContext` is defined. What class owns `GetSubmissionDetailsAsync` ?

Comment: Passed in from constructor

Comment: @retide That doesn't answer my question at all. Please show us the _full_ `class` definition **and** where/how that class is instantiated.

Comment: Hi. I have update the code sections

Comment: Updated the code sections

Answer (score 0):

Although the DbContext implements IDisposable, you shouldn't manually dispose it, nor should you wrap it in a using statement. DbContext manages its own lifetime; when your data access request is completed, DbContext will automatically close the database connection for you.
You can check this post and the answer there is given by Diego Vega (the Senior SDE Lead on EF)
https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/

There are special cases in which dispose should be applied, but
according to the code you provided above, there is no need to explicitly apply dispose.

Comment: *DbContext manages its own lifetime*. That's not true. Implementing `IDisposable` doesn't mean that the object disposes itself. It means it can *be* disposed, which is passive. But yes, by default, the context closes connections after each db interaction so usually it's not even worth worrying whether it's disposed or not. (It takes deliberate steps to make a context not close the connection).

Comment: I did not say that dbContext dispose itself, but  manages itself so that it is not necessary to call dispose . Оf course except in special cases.

Comment: I edited my post , because I had error that causes confusion in the sense of what I have written.

Comment: But it doesn't manage its own *lifetime*. As the post says, it manages its own *connection*.

Comment: All you are saying it is not need to manually call dispose method. And dbcontext will handle close connection itself. 
So i should not worry  about memory leak from my code ?

Comment: The default automatic open/close behavior is relatively easy to override: you can assume control of when the connection is opened and closed by manually opening the connection. Once you start doing this in some part of your code, then forgetting to dispose the context becomes harmful, because you might be leaking open connections. In that case you can dispose the context if you are not sure is the connection opened automatically or manually.

Comment: For the lifetime of the dbContext you can check this post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507691/entity-framework-core-service-default-lifetime

Comment: I have tested my codes I can see I am hold the dbcontext to long. The phonetical risk is hold dbcontext too long.
exmaple:
call sp1-> do somework -> call sp 2-> do somework -> close connection.
It is working on if the traffic is low.
when traffic is high I feel it will run out connections.
It should be sp1->dispose dbcontext->do somework -> call sp2 -> dispose context -> do some work