# Cannot consume scoped service IMongoDbContext from singleton IActiveUsersService after upgrade to ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I updated a project to ASP.NET Core 2 today and I get the following error:

> Cannot consume scoped service IMongoDbContext from singleton IActiveUsersService

I have the following registration:

```
services.AddSingleton<IActiveUsersService, ActiveUsersService>();
services.AddScoped<IMongoDbContext, MongoDbContext>();
services.AddSingleton(option =>
{
   var client = new MongoClient(MongoConnectionString.Settings);
   return client.GetDatabase(MongoConnectionString.Database);
})



public class MongoDbContext : IMongoDbContext
{
   private readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

   public MongoDbContext(IMongoDatabase database)
   {
      _database = database;
   }

   public IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>() where T : Entity, new()
   {
      return _database.GetCollection<T>(new T().CollectionName);
   }
}

public class IActiveUsersService: ActiveUsersService
{

   public IActiveUsersService(IMongoDbContext mongoDbContext)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Why DI can't consume the service? All works fine for ASP.NET Core 1.1.

Comment: Why do you even want to have the Mongo context be scoped in the first place? Do you have some kind of tenant functionality, where you know the tenant id only at runtime? [MongoDatabase](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase.htm) is thread safe, so you can also keep it as singleton (assuming you don't run 100s of it which keep to many connections open). EF Core on the other side is not thread safe and has a caching mechanism on by default (EF Core tracking also acts as caching), so it's natural to have it scoped)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use DbContext in ASP .Net Singleton Injected Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332239/use-dbcontext-in-asp-net-singleton-injected-class)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You can't use a service with a smaller lifetime. Scoped services only exist per-request, while singleton services are created once and the instance is shared.

Now only one instance of `IActiveUsersService` exists in the app. But it wants to depend on `MongoDbContext`, which is Scoped, and is created per-request.

You will have to either:

1. Make `MongoDbContext` a Singleton, or
2. Make `IActiveUsersService` Scoped, or
3. Pass `MongoDbContext` into the user service as a function argument

Comment: Make sense, but, what if I have another class, `MyService` for example, it's scoped and I want to have scoped `MongoDbContext` for this service.

Comment: You can't have different lifetimes (without different interfaces for example). Why do you want to have a scoped version for that one? If a service can be singleton, it should be singleton. If it can't, but it can be scoped, it should be scoped. If it can't be scoped, it should be transient.

Comment: Thanks, makes totally sense - but I wonder why it was possible in ASP.NET Core 1.0? Was a bit confusing.

Comment: I think the error was only added in 2.0. In certain situations it may have worked, but basically you should not do it.

Answer (score 55):

**There are important differences between Scoped and Singleton services.** The warning is there to bring this to light, and turning it off or switching around lifetimes indiscriminately to make it go away won't solve the problem.

Scoped services are created from an `IServiceScope`. One of its most important purposes is to ensure that any `IDisposable` services which are created in that scope are properly disposed when the scope itself is.

In ASP.NET Core, a service scope is automatically created for you on each incoming request, so you ordinarily don't need to worry about this. However, you can also create your own service scope; you just need to dispose of it yourself.

One way to do this is to:

- make your singleton service `IDisposable`,
- inject `IServiceProvider`,
- create and store an `IServiceScope` scope using the [`IServiceProvider.CreateScope()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.createscope?view=aspnetcore-2.1) extension method,
- use that scope to create the the scoped service you need,
- dispose the service scope in the `Dispose` method.

```
services.AddSingleton<IActiveUsersService, ActiveUsersService>();
services.AddScoped<IMongoDbContext, MongoDbContext>();
services.AddSingleton(option =>
{
   var client = new MongoClient(MongoConnectionString.Settings);
   return client.GetDatabase(MongoConnectionString.Database);
})

public class MongoDbContext : IMongoDbContext
{
   private readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

   public MongoDbContext(IMongoDatabase database)
   {
      _database = database;
   }

   public IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>() where T : Entity, new()
   {
      return _database.GetCollection<T>(new T().CollectionName);
   }
}

public class ActiveUsersService: IActiveUsersService, IDisposable
{
   private readonly IServiceScope _scope;

   public ActiveUsersService(IServiceProvider services)
   {
      _scope = services.CreateScope(); // CreateScope is in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
   }

   public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFooData()
   {
       using (var context = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMongoDbContext>())
       {
           return context.GetCollection<Foo>();
       }
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
       _scope?.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Depending on how you're using these and the scoped services you're consuming, you could instead do one of the following:

- create a single instance of the scoped service and use it for the life of the singleton; or
- store a reference to the (injected) root `IServiceProvider`, use it to create a new `IServiceScope` inside a `using` block every time you need a scoped service, and let the scope get disposed when the block exits.

Just keep in mind that any `IDisposable` services created from an `IServiceScope` will get automatically disposed when the scope itself does.

In short, don't just change around the lifetimes of your services to "make it work"; you still need to think about those and be sure they get disposed properly. ASP.NET Core handles the most common cases automatically; for others, you just need to do a bit more work.

Ever since C# 1.0 we have had `using()` blocks to ensure resources are disposed correctly. But `using()` blocks don't work when something else (the DI service) is creating those resources for you. That's where Scoped services come in, and using them incorrectly will lead to resource leaks in your program.

Comment: Is `BeginScope()` equivalent to `ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.CreateScope()`? Perhaps it has been renamed?

Comment: @gt yes it is, not sure if it was renamed or I just mis-typed it but I fixed the example & added link, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can also add

```
.UseDefaultServiceProvider(options =>
                    options.ValidateScopes = false)
```

before `.Build()` in `Program.cs` file to disable the validation.

Try this only for development testing, ActiveUsersService is singleton and has a larger lifetime than MongoDbContext which is scoped and will not get disposed.

Comment: What's the default value for `ValidateScopes`?

Comment: @JimAho default value is false. I have used the following successfully `.UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => { })`

Answer (score 7):

There is another way to approach this issue, and it is by adding the `MongoDbContext` to the DI as `AddTransient` like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IActiveUsersService, ActiveUsersService>();
services.AddTransient<IMongoDbContext, MongoDbContext>();
```

The meaning of using this approach is that you'll end up with an instance of `MongoDbContext` for each `Singleton` class you have using it.
For example, if you have 10 Singleton classes using `MongoDbContext` you'll have 10 instances of it, but it's instead of creating an instance for every request.

See this for reference: [Cannot Consume Scoped Service From Singleton – A Lesson In ASP.net Core DI Scopes](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/03/20/cannot-consume-scoped-service-from-singleton-a-lesson-in-asp-net-core-di-scopes/)

Answer (score 4):

From Constructor Injection, a long `Lifetime` service can't request a shorter `Lifetime` service.. 
The reason is that the longer lifetime service will use the shorter lifetime service for longer time than it was specified.
The instance of shorter service can't be updated as often as needed.

The following options are allowed:

```
          | Transient | Scoped | Singleton
-------------------------------------------
Transient |     +     |    +   |     +
-------------------------------------------
Scoped    |     -     |    +   |     +
-------------------------------------------
Singleton |     -     |    -   |     +
```

This exception is only shown for `Development` environment and not `Production`

Answer (score 3):

Since some input parameters of the constructor are not interface, engine can not inject an object into the class.

use `AddScoped` rather than `AddSingleton`, it maybe resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to create a singleton caching class which used a scoped EF Db Context. I came up with this class which I registed as a singleton. Take care with it though as calling `Create` on the same factory instance might return the same DB context which can be dangerous.

```
// Allows singleton lifetime classes to obtain DB contexts which has the same
// lifetime as the MyDbContextFactory
MyDbContextFactory : IMyDbContextFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceScope? _scope;

    public MyDbContextFactory(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
    }

    public IMyDbContext Create()
    {
        if (_scope == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Failed creating scope");

        }

        return _scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyDbContext>();
    }
}
```

Actually you can register the factory as Transient and it still works.