# AddSingleton doesn't work in my ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, singleton

I have the problem that I want to add my service CourseService as Singleton and I want to add **only once** my initial data like this:

```
context.Courses.Add(new Course { ... });
```

But it turned out that every time when I upload my page with courses my initial data added again and again to my database. So I see the same courses on my page as much time as I upload this page. Can't understand where is the problem.

My interface:

```
public interface ICourseService
{
    IEnumerable<CourseDto> GetCourses();
    Task<IEnumerable<CourseDto>> GetCoursesAsync();
}
```

My service:

```
public class CourseService : BaseService<Course, CourseDto>, ICourseService
{
        public CourseService(IMapper mapper, DataContext context) : base(mapper,context)
        {
            context.Courses.Add(new Course { ... });
            context.Courses.Add(new Course { ... });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public IEnumerable<CourseDto> GetCourses() { ... }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<CourseDto>> GetCoursesAsync() { ... }
}
```

My controller:

```
public class CourseController : Controller
{
        private readonly CourseService _courseService;

        public CourseController(CourseService courseService)
        {
            _courseService = courseService;
        }

        [Route("courses")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCourses()
        {
            var courses = await _courseService.GetAllAsync();
            return View("CourseList", courses);
        }
}
```

And I added my service as Singleton in the method ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICourseService, CourseService>();
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<DataContext>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AddDbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions-adddbcontext-1(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-action((microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextoptionsbuilder))-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicelifetime-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicelifetime)) by default adds context with `Scoped` lifetime, so it can't be resolved in singleton services. Possible workarounds:

1. register `ICourseService` as scoped
2. register context as scoped or transient (would not recommend)
3. inject `IServiceScopeFactory` and use it to create scope and resolve context from the scope (on each method call), like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73619021/2501279)

Personally I would go with the first approach.

Read more:

- [Service lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes)
- [Data seeding in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding)

Comment: Tried to register ICourseService as scoped, it doesn't work, my data is added again every time when I refresh this page. And tried the 3rd approach - the same issue

Comment: @Nika for initial data - look into [data seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding).