# Resolve dependency for constructor parameters interface in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm getting an 500 error on request if adding the `IVoltRepository`  parameters in constructor.

If I remove the parameter `IVoltRepository` from the constructor, request will be handled ok.

I've already registered services for DI:

```
public class VoltProcessing : IVoltProcessing
{
        private readonly IVoltRepository _voltRepository;
        private readonly ILoggingAttributes _loggingAttributes;

        public VoltProcessing(IVoltRepository voltrepository, ILoggingAttributes loggingAttributes)
        {
            _voltRepository = voltrepository;
            _loggingAttributes = loggingAttributes;
        }
}

services.AddScoped<IVoltRepository, VoltRepository>();                 
services.AddSingleton<IVoltProcessing, VoltProcessing>();
```

I'm getting the 500 error if am using `IVoltRepository` as a parameter in the `VoltProcessing` constructor.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot consume scoped service from singleton, try:

```
services.AddScoped<IVoltProcessing, VoltProcessing>();
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810851/cannot-consume-scoped-service-imongodbcontext-from-singleton-iactiveusersservice) to know more.

> You can't use a service with a smaller lifetime. Scoped services only
> exist per-request, while singleton services are created once and the
> instance is shared.

Comment: Hi @lalit sharma If my answer help you resolve your issue ?

Comment: Hi @Qing Guo , i change the singleton to scope but still getting error .

Comment: @lalit sharma what's your error  message?