# How to resolve a ObjectDisposedException that occurs in a Blazor Component using a Timer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, timer, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I am currently trying to use a Timer (System.Timers) within a Blazor component to update an entity using an Injected DBContext. However when it reaches the Save Changes method it simply shows the following error

[image]
[image: Disposed Exception]

Here is the my Startup.cs file DbContext section:
[image: Startup.cs]

My Blazor Component CS looks like this:
[image: Blazor Component]

**What I think the Problem Is**

I think the problem is that the Timer class is on a different thread and therefore isn't in scope to access to the DbContext.

What I don't know is, if I am right, how to pass the DbContext properly to the Timer or how to call the Save Changes method from the main thread.

I did try to use a DBContextPool (as shown below) but it doesn't work. I am guessing it's still due to the thread being different from the main thread.

[image: DbContextPool]

If you need any more details please just let me know so I can gather the exact details.

**Update 1 07/20/2020**

I attempted to move the logic into a service. That service then has a DbContext injected into it however I got the same error message but the error happened in the new ActionService class.

Here is the new ActionService

[image]

And here is the Startup.cs change

[image]

Here is the Blazor Component Update

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code and errors as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images are problematic for [many reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), including that they don't allow copy-pasting text for testing or searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates your DbContext was disposed of before your timer fires. It's not related to the thread the code executes on (though as a separate issue, DbContext instances are not thread-safe).

I have not used Blazor so might miss something specific to it, but you might consider having your timer instantiate a new class that has a DbContext injected into it, passing in whatever data is needed to update the database.

You might also look at configuring your [class lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to be `scoped`. The downside is that you would hold an instance of your DbContext for each user connected to your service.

Comment: I haven't tried your solution yet however I feel fairly confident about it. I am going to try your "Service" class and have my DBContext injected. I will confirm your answer once I am able to verify

Comment: Have a peak at my update on the original post. I think that is what you were suggesting. However it appears to give me the exact same error message. Hopefully I did what you were going for.

Comment: Your ActionService is still instantiated within the lifetime of your original object, so it is also disposed when your original object is disposed.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747931/server-side-timer-with-dbcontext

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much. I have marked this as the answer to my question.

Comment: If you are using .Net 5 then you can also try to use DbContextFactory as that was made for something like this.