# Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: INewsRepository Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: NewsRepository':

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, repository, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-3.0

I try get data from my database with repository Pattern 
i have 3 project

> Bmu.Mode 'this is for model to create database'
>
> Bmu.Repo 'it have 2 folder for repository include contract/InewsRepository.cs' and 'Repository/NewsRepository' for implement Interface
>
> Bmu.Api for invoke data from Repo project

news class in Model Project

```
namespace bmu.model
{
   public class News
   {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SubTitle { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Summery { get; set; }
  }
}
```

context class in model project

```
namespace bmu.model
 {
   public class BmuContext : DbContext
    {
       public BmuContext(DbContextOptions<BmuContext> options): base(options)
      {

      }
    public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
   }
}
```

My interface in Repo project

```
namespace bmu.repo.Contracts
{
  public interface INewsRepository
  {
    Task<IEnumerable<News>> GetAllAsync();
    Task<IEnumerable<News>> GetAllActiveAsync();
  }
}
```

implement interface in bmu.repo

```
namespace bmu.repo.IRepository
{
 public class NewsRepository : INewsRepository
 {
    private readonly BmuContext _context;
    private readonly MemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public NewsRepository(BmuContext context, MemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _context = context;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<News>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _context.News.ToListAsync(); 
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<News>> GetAllActiveAsync()
    {
      return   await _context.News.Where(x => x.Active).ToListAsync();
    }

}
}
```

Also add

```
services.AddControllers(); 
        services.AddSingleton<INewsRepository, NewsRepository>();
```

in startup of Api project
 and this is my controller

```
namespace bmu.api.Controllers
{
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class NewsController : ControllerBase
{
     private readonly ILogger<NewsController> _logger;
     private readonly INewsRepository _newsRepository;

    public NewsController(ILogger<NewsController> logger,INewsRepository newsRepository)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _newsRepository = newsRepository; 
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<News>> Get()
    {
        return await _newsRepository.GetAllActiveAsync();
    }
}
}
```

but when run project i got this error

> AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: bmu.repo.Contracts.INewsRepository Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: bmu.repo.IRepository.NewsRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'bmu.model.BmuContext' while attempting to activate 'bmu.repo.IRepository.NewsRepository'.)

also because of multi project add DbContext with this

***UPDATE:***

```
namespace bmu.model
{
public class BmuContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BmuContext>
{
    public BmuContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BmuContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=bmu.db");

        return new BmuContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
}
```

Is there any solution for this error ?

Answer (score -11, accepted):

It was because of

```
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
```

when i remove it every think work fine

Comment: Your answer is not logical.

Comment: I think its because of don't register IMemoryCache in startup.cs in service, it logical

Comment: Is IMemoryCache  was registerd in startup.cs?

Comment: Also, you should sign Rena's answer as an accepted answer

Comment: I'd also add to @malik comment: You should sign Rena's answer as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 33):

Firstly,you need to change:

```
services.AddSingleton<INewsRepository, NewsRepository>();
```

To:

```
services.AddTransient<INewsRepository, NewsRepository>();
```

Secondly,you need to inject `IMemoryCache` instead of `MemoryCache` in `NewsRepository`.

Here is a simple demo like below:

1.Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddSession();
    services.AddTransient<INewsRepository, NewsRepository>();
    services.AddDbContext<BmuContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connectionstring")));
    services.AddMemoryCache();
}
```

2.appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Connectionstring": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Bmu;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"  
}
```

3.NewsRepository:

```
public class NewsRepository : INewsRepository
{
    private readonly BmuContext _context;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public NewsRepository(BmuContext context, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: I do All of think, remove " private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;" from Repository and avery think work fine

Comment: In my case, i created non-public constructor.
Resolved by creating it public and it works.

Answer (score 26):

My Error was that I was injecting the **service class** instead of the **interface**

It was

```
  //This is wrong
Private readonly DataSerive _dataService;
public void EmployeeHandler(DataSerive dataService)
{
_dataService = dataService;
}
```

But it should be

```
 //This is correct
Private readonly IDataSerive _dataService;
public void EmployeeHandler(IDataSerive dataService)
{
_dataService = dataService;
}
```

Here **DataService** is the **class** that handles operation
and **IDataService** is the **interface**

Comment: this. chances are you need to use the interface instead of the class, or vice versa. In my case I needed to implement ILogger<T> instead of Logger<T>

Answer (score 10):

There is a lifetime type mismatch in your API. EntityFramework DbContext is a scoped service, and you cannot have a singleton instance of the NewsRepository, as it depends on an instance that is generated for each request.

You either have to use NewsRepository as a scoped service, or restructure your dependency resolution, like shown in this SO answer: [Use DbContext in ASP .Net Singleton Injected Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332239/use-dbcontext-in-asp-net-singleton-injected-class)

Comment: I use  services.AddScoped<INewsRepository, NewsRepository>();but get this error again

Comment: How are you registering your BmuContext?

Comment: services.AddDbContext<BmuContext>(); Also update my question

Comment: I see you are only setting up the options for designtime, not in your Startup.cs. I expect a services.AddDbContext<BmuContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(your connection string)); instead

Answer (score 4):

Like  Sotiris Koukios-Panopoulos -san comment

I see you are only setting up the options for design time, not in your `Startup.cs`. I expect a:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<BmuContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("your connection string"));
```

instead.

In my case, I forgot to set this in my `Startup.cs`

```cs
services.AddDbContext<myDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
```

and I forgot to mention this, because I'm using interface an service

```cs
services.AddScoped<IMyTruckService, MyTruckService>();
```

Answer (score 2):

I was adding `singleton` service that was injecting `DbContext` class.

```
services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
```

I changed above to below (Added a `transient` service scope) and it worked.

```
services.AddTransient<FoodItemService>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was that alluded to in @sotiris-panopoulos alternative.

see if bmu.repo.Contracts.INewsRepository has a reference to another object that  ALSO must be a part of your buider.

In my app, I was having this issue on

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ShiftMessageDetailService>();
```

In my ShiftMessageDetailService there I'm using a IDbContextFactory object

```
 private IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _dbContextFactory;
```

So there is a Service type "Mismatch" because the ShiftMessageDetailService is scoped, and the ApplicationDbContext is null

so, the fix for me was also build the AddDbContextFactory.  It did fix the problem, the part I'm a bit confused is AddDbContextFactory scoped or transient or singleton - or is that dynamic? I'm not sure but it just can't be null and the issue went away.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("LCPVconnection")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<ShiftMessageDetailService>();
```

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused by circular dependency.
Because probably, you inject service1 in service2 and also service2 in service1.
You should change it and break circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I was having two dbcontext, and  forgotten to mention this in startup.cs file

```
services.AddDbContext<Abc>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConStr")));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. its not clear if your post is answering the original question. If you believe your post answers it, please elaborate why and how with more detail

Answer (score 0):

**In my case, I created a constructor method in my service by accident:**

```
public class NewsRepository: INewsRepository 
{
    public NewsRepository(INewsRepository newsRepository)
    {
    // code ....        
    }
// code ....
 }
```

This generates circular dependency and a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this:

```
    services.AddScoped<IDummyRepository, DummyRepository>();
    services.AddHostedService<TestBackgroundService >();
```

and then

```
public class TestBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public TestBackgroundService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // here is the magic 
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var dummyRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDummyRepository>();
            
            dummyRepository.DoWork();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a nice time

To solve this problem, it is enough to change the way of calling the DB context in the interface

Example:

```
  private readonly DataBaseContext _context;
    public TestRepository(DataBaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

To:

```
private readonly DataBaseContext _context;
        public TestRepository()
        {
            _context = new DataBaseContext();
        }
```

I am Farhad Rezvani from Iran.