# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, dependency-injection, rich-domain-model

Is it possible to have interfaces with other paramaters together like here below?
I do this because I have private setters and have one constructor.

**planning constructor (Logic)**

```
public Planning(
    IPlanningDAL planningDAL,
    IPlanningParticipantDAL planningParticipantDAL,
    ICategoryCollectionDAL categoryCollectionDAL,
    ITaskCollectionDAL taskCollectionDAL,
    ITaskDAL taskDAL,
    IParticipantDAL participantDAL,
    ICategoryDAL categoryDAL,
    int id,
    string name,
    DateTime startDate,
    DateTime? endDate,
    Participant leader)
{
    this.planningDAL = planningDAL;
    this.planningParticipantDAL = planningParticipantDAL;
    this.categoryCollectionDAL = categoryCollectionDAL;
    this.taskCollectionDAL = taskCollectionDAL;
    this.taskDAL = taskDAL;
    this.participantDAL = participantDAL;
    this.categoryDAL = categoryDAL;
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
    StartDate = startDate;
    EndDate = endDate;
    Leader = leader;
}
```

**ASP.NET Core MVC program**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<Planning>();
```

**error**

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Logic.Models.Planning Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Logic.Models.Planning': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Int32' while attempting to activate 'Logic.Models.Planning'.)

Comment: Show the *full* error message, that will tell you exactly what the problem is. But here's a start: Do you have a `services.AddScoped<IPlanningDAL, PlanningDAL>()` line too? How about for all of the other constructor parameters?

Comment: where do you expect DI to get things like `id`, `name`, `startDate` etc from? Services are one thing, DI is good at that, but runtime values... you'll need some way of injecting them in

Comment: Also, please post the error message as _text_ not an image - it tells you the same as what im telling you above!

Comment: @DavidG, Yes I have this line services.AddScoped<IPlanningDAL, PlanningDAL>() too. how should I implement your idea?

Comment: @Jamiec I don't have much experience, that's why I'm here. When I seperate this constructor into 2 constructors then I don't have acces to my DAL. So what should I do?

Comment: Mixing design-time dependencies with runtime data in the constructor is not a good idea. Please read [this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/) article for more information.

Comment: If `Planning` is a Domain Entity, you are better of using [Method Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-method-injection/) on those design-time dependencies instead of using Constructor Injection. Refrain from registering Domain Entities in your DI Container; DI is unsuited for data-centric objects such as Domain Entities.

Comment: @Jamiec if my properties were public setters, I removed them of my constructor and there was no issue. But my teacher does not allow me to have public setters related to encapsulation. "you'll need some way of injecting them in", how?

Comment: @abus you have your architecture all wrong. If `Planning` is a class which represents a thing with an `id` then it shouldnt have services, If it is a layer which requires services, it shouldnt have properties like `id`

Answer (score 0):

A question similar to your question asked before.
I think the following link can help you .

[Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: INewsRepository Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: NewsRepository':](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328439/error-while-validating-the-service-descriptor-servicetype-inewsrepository-life)

Answer (score 0):

From the context of the question I distilled the following:

- `Planning` represents an [entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity#In_computer_science) and considering the number of design-time dependencies (such as your `IPlanningDAL`) the class has, it seems you are trying to apply some sort of [Domain-Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). An entity is an object that is primarily defined by its identity (e.g. the `int Id` in your case).
- The more-primitive properties `int Id`, `string Name`, `DateTime StartDate`, DateTime? EndDate`, and` Participant Leader` seem values define the entity's current state, rather than configuration values that stay unchanged for all entities in the system and while the system is running.
- By supplying the entity's data values through the constructor you seem to be trying to protect the [class's invariant](https://www.programming-books.io/essential/java/encapsulation-to-maintain-invariants-f8cb907288f34d39858325f9b74ea77c). This is a common approach when practicing Domain-Driven Design where you prevent direct mutation of individual properties from the outside, but rather let consumers change the state of an entity through methods on the entity.

The remainder of my answer rest on the previous assumptions.

Object Composition, in the context of Dependency Injection, is meant to compose application *components* like a behavior-centric `SqlPlanningDAL`. It's not meant for the construction of data-centric object like entities. The use of DI Containers exaggerate this, because it becomes hard to create data-centric objects with design-time dependencies when using a DI Container such as the built-in ASP.NET Core DI Container Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (MS.DI). This means that adding `Planning` to the Container such as you are doing here is not a good idea:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<Planning>();
```

The reason for this is that although the container can supply the configured design-time dependencies to the class, it has no way of knowing what *runtime values* it should provide. And how could it? These values will change for each entity and are typically loaded from some data source.

This means that any time the construction of an object requires both runtime data and design-time dependencies (as with your `Planning` entity), object composition gets complicated, which is why I consider [injecting runtime data into components a code DI smell](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/).

A way to solve this is by moving the creation of `Planning` to a repository of some sort (likely your `PlanningDAL`):

```cs
// WARNING: Not an ideal solution
public class PlanningDal : IPlanningDal
{
    public PlanningDal(
        IPlanningDAL planningDAL,
        IPlanningParticipantDAL planningParticipantDAL,
        ICategoryCollectionDAL categoryCollectionDAL,
        ITaskCollectionDAL taskCollectionDAL,
        ITaskDAL taskDAL,
        IParticipantDAL participantDAL,
        ICategoryDAL categoryDAL) ...

    public Planning GetById(int id)
    {
        PlanningData data = LoadPlanningDataFromDatabase(id);

        return new Planning(
            this.planningDAL,
            this.planningParticipantDAL,
            this.categoryCollectionDAL,
            this.taskCollectionDAL,
            this.taskDAL,
            this.participantDAL,
            this.categoryDAL,
            data.Id,
            data.Name,
            data.StartDate,
            data.EndDate,
            data.Participant);
    }
}
```

Although this could certainly technically work, this model will —in the long run— likely become a maintenance nightmare. This is because in an evolving domain, new domain logic will be added regularly, which will force changes to both the `PlanningDal` (i.e. your repository) and the `Planning` entity.

A more commonly-used —and more-maintainable— model is to move `Planning`'s design-time dependencies to specific methods on `Planning` that require their use. So instead of applying them using [Constructor Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-constructor-injection/), you use [Method Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-method-injection/) instead. This means that only the entity's data values will be applied to the constructor:

```cs
public class Planning : IEntity
{
    // Make setters private to protect invariants.
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; private set; }
    public Participant Participant { get; private set; }

    // Only supply runtime data here
    public Planning(
        int id, string name, DateTime startDate, DateTime? endDate, Participant leader)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
        Leader = leader;
    }
    
    // Here you implement the logic where you pass on -only- the design-time dependencies
    // that are required for the method to function. The method should not store the
    // dependencies; only use them.
    public void ReplaceParticipant(
        Participant participant, IPlanningParticipantDAL planningParticipantDAL)
    {
        ...
        this.Participant = participant;
    }    
}
```

This does mean, however, that those dependencies must be supplied by consumers of these domain methods. For instance:

```cs
public class ReplaceParticipantHandler : ICommandHandler<ReplaceParticipant>
{
    private readonly IPlanningDAL planningDAL;
    private readonly IParticipantDAL participantDal;
    private readonly IPlanningParticipantDAL planningParticipantDal;

    public ReplaceParticipantHandler(
        IPlanningDAL planningDAL,
        IParticipantDAL participantDal,
        IPlanningParticipantDAL planningParticipantDal)
    {
        this.planningDAL = planningDAL;
        this.participantDal = participantDal;
        this.planningParticipantDal = planningParticipantDal;
    }
    
    public void Handle(ReplaceParticipant command)
    {
        // Load entities using repositories
        var planning = this.planningDAL.GetById(command.PlanningId);
        var participant = this.planningParticipantDAL.GetById(command.NewParticipantId);
        
        // Invoke domain method
        planning.ReplaceParticipant(participant, this.planningParticipantDal);
        
        // use repository to persist the entity
        this.planningDAL.Save(planning);
    }
}
```