# How to add Identity to your MVC project

Tags: c#, .net, identity

After I added Identity to my project, I keep getting to this error message when I try to run the project

```
    using CandySoap.Data;
using CandySoap.DataAccess.Repository;
using CandySoap.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionLink")));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();;

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

```
namespace CandySoap.Data
{
    public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> option) : base(option) { }
        public DbSet<Category> categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Covertype> covertypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> Error message:constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: CandySoap.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: CandySoap.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork': Unable to resolve

```
using CandySoap.Data;
using CandySoap.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;

namespace CandySoap.DataAccess.Repository
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private ApplicationContext _db;

        public UnitOfWork(ApplicationContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            Category = new CategoryRepository(_db);
            Covers = new CovertypesRepository(_db);
            Product = new ProductRepository(_db);

        }
        public ICategoryRepository Category { get; private set; }

        public ICovertypesRepository Covers { get; private set; }

        public IProductRepository Product { get; private set; }

        public void Save()
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

er code here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: INewsRepository Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: NewsRepository':](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328439/error-while-validating-the-service-descriptor-servicetype-inewsrepository-life)

Comment: According to the code and the error message you showed, it said there is something wrong about your `UnitofWork`, so if possible, please show this part of codes and let’s see if there’s something wrong on this part.